# SWT List cell renderer

Tags: swt

How to set a cell renderer for SWT list? I want to have a list with text, and every line must have a different foreground.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172496). What may be confusing you is that [Stack Overflow is not like all those other sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128554/172496)

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but that cannot be done for list, only for a Table. See [Table example snippet: draw different foreground colors for text in a TableItem](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet236.java).